# unable to refer System.Threading.Volatile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.5

I've just installed final version of .NET Framework 4.5 and rebooted. I'm using VS 2010.
I've tried to use new [System.Threading.Volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg712929) class but I receive "Cannot resolve symbol" error when using `System.Threading.Volatile`.

In project properties target framework version is ".NET Framework 4" which I suppose includes 4.5

Why I can't refer `System.Threading.Volatile` and how to resolve my problem? Have I to use VS 2012 for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use .NET 4.5 from Visual Studio 2010.  You need to install VS 2012 to target .NET 4.5 and use new types defined only in 4.5.

> In project properties target framework version is ".NET Framework 4" which I suppose includes 4.5

No, it does not.  It only includes classes and types in .NET 4.  You need to target ".NET Framework 4.5", which requires VS 2012.